# Google Script to copy rows from one sheet to another when a checkbox is checked

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In Google Sheets, I have a sheet of data and all the cells in column "G" have a checkbox. Is there a script or formula that could be set up for rows to be copied over to another sheet when the checkbox is checked? This would save time and avoid doing another task. Thank you.

Comment: Post what you tried so far, we are not here to do your job, but ot help you. You will never learn if someone codes something for you.

Please take a few seconds reading how to include a [complete and verifiable](https://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example and, please, avoid asking or editing this post before reading it.

Comment: Yep this is a common question here, so do your homework and review similar questions. Don't forget to try and implement or adapt what you find - it's pretty unlikely you'll find a turn-key solution, but very likely you can get something working with trivial modifications.

Comment: I understand but I am not a coder and I do not code in my job. I was trying to figure this out to make a task easier in a spreadsheet I work in. I had already spent several hours that I shouldn't have.

Answer (score 2):

The checkbox (say in ColumnZ) is equivalent to TRUE for a query, so something like:

```
=query(Sheet1!A:Z,"where Z=TRUE")
```

This does not apply GAS, it is just a regular formula.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it didn't work. I received "Syntax error. (line 2, file "Code")"